# Node inspect in chrome does not show source files

Tags: node.js, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, node-inspector

Node inspect does not show source code to debug in chrome devtools.
I tried to run code using command

```
node --inspect server.js
```

then i opened chrome://inspect/#devices
and then clicked Open dedicated DevTools for Node.
But this doesn't show up my server.js file but shows recently opened files in devtools.

Comment: Is there any update of this issue?

Comment: no, ping me if you find some

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem. There is an issue in chrome. Here is the link of the issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=941608#c15

By updating chrome into beta version, solve my problem.