# Chrome DevTools does not show any source files

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, node-debugger

I have a Node app running on a remote server. I've added it as a remote target on my local Chrome and then click "inspect", which jumps me into the debugger.

The debugger is clearly working and able to control the target. And if I pause on an exception it will show me the source file where the exception happened.

But the "Sources" tab shows no source files. I can click "Add folder to workspace" but this shows me an open dialog to select a folder on my local development machine's filesystem.

How do I view files on the remote system? The debugger is fairly useless if I cannot set a breakpoint on a specific line.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55487488/node-inspect-in-chrome-does-not-show-source-files) asked the same but it seemed to be a resolved bug.

Comment: Seems  I can at least use Cmd-P to type in a path.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your configuration of sourcemaps or a bug in devtools.